# Node.Js convert non english digits to english digits on the fly

Tags: javascript, node.js

this below prototype can convert non English digits to English digits such as :

`۱‍‍` -> `1` Or `۲` -> `2`

all of none English digits are Persian and Arabic and i'm trying to convert theme to English digits on the fly for below code:

```
const result = $(".ExRate-TR").map((i, element) => ({
        currency: $(element).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text().trim(),
        price: $(element).find('td:nth-of-type(3)').text().trim().toEnDigit()
    })).get();
```

but after that i don't get result and prototype cause of i get empty result

```
String.prototype.toEnDigit = function() {
    return this.replace(/[\u06F0-\u06F9]+/g, function(digit) {
        var ret = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = digit.length; i < len; i++) {
            ret += String.fromCharCode(digit.charCodeAt(i) - 1728);
        }
        return ret;
    });
};
```

how can i resolve this problem and using `toEnDigit` end of string?

Comment: Your `toEnDigit` function works fine.  Can you verify what the value of `$(element).find('td:nth-of-type(3)').text().trim()` is?

Comment: @just.another.programmer Yes, you right, Thanks